# Non transparent ssl/tls Mitm proxy for reverse engineering a device

Tags: linux, encryption, proxy

1 way of deciphering https in mitm is as follow :

1. You create a fake certificate authority
2. You manually install it on the target device.
3. You use a special proxy that’ll dynamically uses the given fake certificate authority to generate certificates on the fly for logging connection contents.

There’s a lot of proxy software for doing this : but all those I found are transparent proxies : This means you have to route the network traffic to the proxy, and on the proxy machine you have to set up rules so that the proxy server fake his ip address instead of replying with it’s own ip address : on Linux, this is done with the [`tproxy`](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/tproxy.html) feature of the kernel : but because I lack money, I’ve only access to a rooted phone which allows me to run Linux application but the android’s kernel lacks the `tproxy` of netfilter. This means the only proxy I can run should work by just listening on tcp port…

This is not a problem if the proxy is a nontransparent 1 : instead of routing, you have to edit proxy settings if it’s supported by the client (which it is).
So is there a proxy for mitm https connections but that uses regular socks/https proxying instead of being transparent ?